# Assistance with XML tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm working on a SQL query (MS SQL) that will output as XML. I need assistance with some tags that have the same tag name, `<CustomInteger>`. What my output should look like is this:

```
   <CustomIntegers>
      <CustomInteger>
        <FieldID>2701</FieldID>
        <Value>15</Value>
      </CustomInteger>
      <CustomInteger>
        <FieldID>2704</FieldID>
        <Value>28</Value>
      </CustomInteger>
      <CustomInteger>
        <FieldID>2705</FieldID>
        <Value>28</Value>
      </CustomInteger>
    </CustomIntegers>
```

But what I'm currently getting is this:

```
<CustomIntegers>
  <CustomInteger>
    <FieldID>2701</FieldID>
    <Value>15</Value>
    <FieldID>2704</FieldID>
    <Value>28</Value>
    <FieldID>2705</FieldID>
    <Value>28</Value>
  </CustomInteger>
</CustomIntegers>
```

I need the `<FieldID>` and `<Value>` tags within its own `<CustomInteger>` tag.

--Creating table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [TermCode] [varchar](5),
    [StudentID] [varchar](9),
    [RegisteredHours] [decimal](7, 4) NULL,
    [CreditsAttempted] [decimal](7, 4) NULL,
    [CreditsEarned] [decimal](7, 4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

--Inserting records

```
Insert into Student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned)
values ('20211', '123456789', '9.0000', '6.0000', '6.0000')

Insert into Student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned)
values ('20211', '234567890', '15.0000', '28.0000', '28.0000')

Insert into Student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned)
values ('20211', '345678901', '12.0000', '30.0000', '27.0000')

Insert into Student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned)
values ('20211', '456789012', '10.0000', '30.0000', '30.0000')

Insert into Student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned)
values ('20211', '567890123', '12.0000', '32.0000', '29.0000')
```

--The code I have so far:

```
select 
'2701' as [CustomInteger/FieldID],
cast(RegisteredHours as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value],
'2704' as [CustomInteger/FieldID],
cast(CreditsAttempted as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value],
'2705' as [CustomInteger/FieldID],
cast(CreditsEarned as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value]
from Student
for xml path('CustomIntegers'), type, elements
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your database MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is MS SQL.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I'm pretty new to posting questions here. I thought I provided all of the items you mentioned except for #4 - SQL Server version.

Comment: And the missing logic in the #2.

Comment: Now you understand importance of the **minimal reproducible example**. Your question tripped on **(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.** The solution that you marked as Answer doesn't match your desired output, i.e. #1 and #3 in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot the values and turn them into XML, inside a correlated subquery (per row)

```sql
SELECT
   (
       SELECT FieldID, Value
       FROM (VALUES
         ('2701',cast(RegisteredHours as int)),
         ('2704',cast(CreditsAttempted as int)),
         ('2705',cast(CreditsEarned as int))
       ) v(FieldID, Value)
       FOR XML PATH('CustomInteger'), TYPE
   ) AS CustomIntegers
FROM Student
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28cc40cbd95454cedfe5ec758f919133)

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It seems that your output XML should be composed of the data from one single row.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @student TABLE (
    [TermCode] [varchar](5),
    [StudentID] [varchar](9),
    [RegisteredHours] [decimal](7, 4) NULL,
    [CreditsAttempted] [decimal](7, 4) NULL,
    [CreditsEarned] [decimal](7, 4) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @student (TermCode, StudentID, RegisteredHours, CreditsAttempted, CreditsEarned) VALUES 
('20211', '123456789', '9.0000', '6.0000', '6.0000'),
('20211', '234567890', '15.0000', '28.0000', '28.0000'),
('20211', '345678901', '12.0000', '30.0000', '27.0000'),
('20211', '456789012', '10.0000', '30.0000', '30.0000'),
('20211', '567890123', '12.0000', '32.0000', '29.0000');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT TRY_CAST(RegisteredHours AS INT) AS RegisteredHours
        , TRY_CAST(CreditsAttempted AS INT) AS CreditsAttempted
        , TRY_CAST(CreditsEarned AS INT) AS CreditsEarned
    FROM @student
    WHERE StudentID = '234567890'
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<CustomIntegers>
{
    for $x in /root/r/*
    return <CustomInteger>
        <FieldID>
        {
            if (local-name($x)="RegisteredHours") then "2701"
            else if (local-name($x)="CreditsAttempted") then "2704"
            else if (local-name($x)="CreditsEarned") then "2705"
            else ()
        }
        </FieldID>
        <Value>{data($x)}</Value>
    </CustomInteger>
}
</CustomIntegers>');
```

**SQL #2**

```
SELECT '2701' as [CustomInteger/FieldID]
    , TRY_CAST(RegisteredHours as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value], NULL
    , '2704' as [CustomInteger/FieldID]
    , TRY_CAST(CreditsAttempted as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value], NULL
    , '2705' as [CustomInteger/FieldID]
    , TRY_CAST(CreditsEarned as int) AS [CustomInteger/Value]
FROM @Student
--WHERE StudentID = '234567890'
FOR XML PATH('CustomIntegers'), TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

**Output**

```
<CustomIntegers>
  <CustomInteger>
    <FieldID>2701</FieldID>
    <Value>15</Value>
  </CustomInteger>
  <CustomInteger>
    <FieldID>2704</FieldID>
    <Value>28</Value>
  </CustomInteger>
  <CustomInteger>
    <FieldID>2705</FieldID>
    <Value>28</Value>
  </CustomInteger>
</CustomIntegers>
```

Comment: Can't understand why you went so complicated on this one. Am I missing something?